# jquery slide show not working

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery slide show that works fine when I run it from my local PC but when I put it on the web server it does not work at all.  See here for what it does: 
http://automatethegame.com/testing/index.html
those 3 images should actually be a slide show. :-)

Any suggestions at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save file as binary mode not text on server because they manipulate them by thinking it's text. secondly i thing if you use Google CDN jQuery then it's make less request to server.

Comment: Perfect.  I figured it was something stupid.  I'll look into that Google CDN thing to.  Thank you for the help!  Thanks to everyone else as well!  stackoverflow FTW!

Answer (score 2):

Your script file (jquery.custom.js) has corrupted newlines.

You uploaded a UTF16 file as text, causing the FTP transfer to insert `\n` characters after each `\r` before the `\0` that precedes the UTF16 `\n`.
This gets the UTF16 encoding out of sync and makes every other line Chinese.

Set your FTP client to binary mode (not text) and upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug:

```
Error: illegal character
Source File: http://automatethegame.com/testing/lib/jquery.custom.js
Line: 1, Column: 20
Source Code:
jQuery.noConflict();਀
```

Remove that illegal character and see what happens.

Comment: Look at the file.  His issue is bigger than that.

Answer (score 0):

You website is displaying illegal character error at line 1 in jquery.custom.js (line 1)